# why are concrete types rarely useful as bases for further derivation

Tags: c++

I read "Concrete types are rarely useful as bases for further derivation"------------ Stroustrup p. 768

How to interpret this? Does it mean that we should get derived class from the base class with pure virtual function? However, I see a lot of code with derived class derived from concrete types.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Lots of code has too much inheritance, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you created a derived class, then replaced every instance of the base class in your program with that derived class.  Did the resulting program behave the same?  If not, then you have introduced some gotchas.  These gotchas will probably be accounted for in the case of a class designed for inheritance (e.g. I've seen some classes designed for inheritance that actually have functions to check if other functions are implemented to allow for the case of them not even existing, e.g. file i/o classes that might be missing seek functionality).  Since an abstract class is always going to have been designed with inheritance in mind but a concrete class might not, this could be unsafe.

The explanation above talks about the case where the resulting derived class is not fully compatible with the base class, which is dangerous.  But what if it *is* fully compatible? In this case, some of the potential [justifications](http://gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm) for using inheritance (instead of composition) fall apart.  We don't have any virtual functions or protected members (if we *do*, then I assume the class was designed for inheritance).  Still, using inheritance in this case is probably pretty safe, though ensuring it really is fully compatible is tough.  I'd rather use composition and be safe.

**Edit:**
The term for what I was talking about above is the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  A shorter explanation would be that in most cases, a derived class of a class not designed for inheritance will either violate Liskov's Substitution Principle or will not be able to accomplish anything useful that could not have been accomplished using composition instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a lot of code like this, but the [masters](http://gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm) are trying to [tell us](http://gotw.ca/publications/mill07.htm) that *inheritance is overrated*.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of saying "inherit to *be* reused, not to reuse". Inherting from concrete classes is often done to reuse some code in that class, which is (now) frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

OLD ANSWER (see edit bellow)

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

When Stroustrup says "Concrete *TYPES* are not useful as bases" he's *not* talking about concrete vs. abstract classes, but about a distinct concept, akin to which came to be called *value types*. In his words,

> "a concrete *TYPE* is the representation of a relatively simple concept with all the operations for the support of that concept. ... a concrete *TYPE* resembles a built-in type. Naturally, the built-in types are all concrete."
> ––– Stroustrup 3rd ed. p. 766

This concept evolved and, for example, in C# and Swift, value types like enums and structs do not support inheritance.

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

Edit:

I recently found what may be an authoritative answer:

> We've decided to take a pass and consistently use these terms:
>
> *base class*: A type that is intended to be derived from (e.g., has a non-final virtual function), and objects of the type are intended to be used only indirectly (e.g., by pointer). [In strict terms, "base class" could be defined as "something we derived from" but we are specifying in terms of intent.]
>
> *concrete type*: a type that is not a base class, and objects of the type are intended to be used directly (not only by pointer/indirection), its size is known, it can typically be allocated anywhere the programmer wants (e.g., stack or statically)
>
> *semiregular type*: a concrete type that is assignable and default-constructible (see `std::semiregular` concept)
>
> *regular type*: a semiregular type that is equality-comparable (see `std::regular` concept)
>
> And a note: Some people use the term 'value type' to mean a regular or semiregular type.

https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/1780#issuecomment-867830866

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that you should not inherit from types like `int`, `float`, or `std::string`. You won't get OO behavior from `int foo(int a)` anyway. Even for `int foo(std::string&)`, the lack of virtual functions in `std::string` means that that `foo` will not call your overrides.